# How to register a helper class for passing object instances in Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a scenario where I need to inject an instance of a type using a helper class. In our system we are currently using Unity to inject that object into various layers.

Here is what I currently have:

```
container.RegisterInstance<ITest, new Test()>();
```

But instead of that I would like to use a helper class that would create the instance for me:

```
container.RegisterInstance<ITest, Helper.GetITestIntance()>();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
container.RegisterType<ITest>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionFactory(o => Helper.GetITestIntance()));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/b71665b9-cc71-4c88-9776-6ccb4f871819 there does not seem to be a direct way. You can either register an instance that will be used, or register a "Type" that the container will instantiate on his own at some moments when it is required. There does not seem to be any way to register a "factory", nor the Type-registering methods do not take any delegates/callbacks..

There **could** be some way with use of Container Extensions - maybe you will be able to intercept the query for an instance and then provide your own response.. I think this a good place to start reading on it:

http://visualizationtools.net/default/unity-objectbuilder-part-i/
http://visualizationtools.net/default/unity-objectbuilder-part-ii/

edit: sorry, sorry, I've overlooked the `LifetimeManager` registration paramter. It seems this is exactly what you are looking for: http://tavaresstudios.com/Blog/post/Writing-Custom-Lifetime-Managers.aspx

So, write a factory in form of LifetimeManager, the creation would be done in GetValue method, and register a Type with your this Manager - and the Unity will ask the manager for object instances.